# Getting RGBA colour from gutenberg colourpicker

Tags: plugins, block-editor, variables

I'm working on a block that has it's own colour picker. This is working fine and I can see my background colour changing however I'm only able to get the hex value for the colour.

I'm changing the colour as it stands by doing:-

```
style={{ backgroundColor: `${tint.hex}` }}
```

Tint is an object returned from the colour picker and I can see that it has a sub object called color that contains rgba values.

How do I get these values and make the backgroundColour use rgba()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean [`wp.components.ColorPicker`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/color-picker/) which is based on [*react-color*](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/), then the `tint` object also contains a `rgb` property with an object of the RGBA value like `{r: 51, g: 51, b: 51, a: 1}`.

So in your code, you can use:

```js
style={{ backgroundColor: `rgba(${tint.rgb.r}, ${tint.rgb.g}, ${tint.rgb.b}, ${tint.rgb.a})` }}
```

And an easy trick to know all the available properties in the color object is by running `console.log( tint )`.. :)

Comment: Sally I had to tweak a couple of things (like make my attribute an object so it can have a default rgba). That aside your answer was correct and it solved my issue! :)